# Why AFNetworking Eating so many Memory？

Tags: ios, afnetworking

When I sent 10000 requests in one second, Xcode showed that this program used 300 MB of memory between the requesting. Even after the request, it cost 190 MB and did not decrease, I do not know why.

This is my code. Forgive my English.

```
NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
for (int i = 1; i <= 10000 ; i ++) {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.baidu.com"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc]initWithRequest:request];
    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"Success!");
    }failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error！%@",error);
    }];
    [queue addOperation:operation];
    usleep(100);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

10000 is not a little number.
You could use raw socket routine designed for large request,eg, `AsyncSelect` socket , or `Completion` socket...